# How Repartitioning of a data frame on frequently used filter column can be helpful in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have been watching some materials here and there about repartitioning and coalesce of Spark data frames. Some said the repartitioning can improve performance if it is done on a filtered column. I don't understand why it is so. I know my question isn't specific since the video I watched didn't elaborate and I couldn't get any responses.

Is that because filtering will result in fewer partitions?

Any insight will be welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by "filtered column"? Lesser partitions isn't always better. Repartitioning is a heavy operation when compared to a filter. If you can elaborate, I will be happy to share my thoughts in detail

Comment: Thanks @VihitShah I meant a frequently used column for filtering by "filtered column". I understood repartition shouldn't be done without a good reason and wanted to make sure the benefit for sure.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what transformation you are doing, if you do that transformation on a partitionned column, it will be faster because it allows the machine to know where each data is. Therefore, the filtering will be faster because it does not have to scan all you data. It can directly "delete" or "select" only the rows you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks! Is that because the Spark optimizer will be utilizing the info?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it. For an instance,

Assume that, on an initial dataset, you repartition on a column and then filter on the same column. This will create a situation where many partitions will then have 0 records after the filter. As your pipeline moves ahead, the tasks for these partitions will end within 0-0.2 secs while a small number of tasks (mapping to the partitions with data) will actually work on the data making the whole pipeline slower.

Rather, I would like the filtered data to be present in all the partitions so that I utilise all the executor cores working on the data.

E.g.;

`Dataset`

`id|category|partition`
`01|A       |1`
`02|A       |1`
`03|B       |1`
`04|B       |1`
`05|C       |2`
`06|C       |2`
`07|D       |2`
`08|D       |2`
`09|E       |2`
`10|E       |2`

Assume that you now repartition on `category`

`id|category|partition`
`01|A       |1`
`02|A       |1`
`03|B       |2`
`04|B       |2`
`05|C       |3`
`06|C       |3`
`07|D       |4`
`08|D       |4`
`09|E       |5`
`10|E       |5`

Now, when you filter `category=2`, you then have 0 records in most partitions. Tasks further in your pipeline on these partitions essentially do not do any work and these executor cores are wasted.

Hope this makes sense.